# Using dependencies from multiple modules dagger 2.11 android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Hi I have two modules  seperated in domain packages in my project  and have  firebase insance service class that injects itself manually using DaggerAppComponent.

Then I have two inject dependencies located on the two modules I mentioned.

ModuleOne has the dependency called storage and ModuleTwo has one called delegator.

When atempting to inject both of these inside my firebase service class, it complains that it can't locate and find the delegator injector from ModuleTwo.

However, if I copy the provides method interface of the delegator into ModuleOne it sort of works(now complains that its bound multiple times but can easily fix that by adding naming convention).

This is a hacky way of doing it which I am not keen to do and just want the ability to use any dependencies from different modules. Is this possible?

Below is my firebase service class

```
class MyInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var delegator: AccountDelegatorContract

    @Inject
    lateinit var Storage: StorageContract

 override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    }
    override fun onTokenRefresh() {
        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(application as MyApplication).build().inject(this)
        val refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token

//        val pianoStorage: PianoStorage = PianoStorage(this)
        sendTokenToServer(refreshToken, storage.getUniqueId())
    }

    private fun sendTokenToServer(refreshToken: String?, uniqueId: String) {
        //TODO: Send this new token to server

        delegator.sendPushToken(PushTokenRequest(refreshToken!!, uniqueId))
    }
```

Here is moduleOne which represents the main Module that houses dependencies that are used in multiple domain packages in my application.

```
@Module
abstract class MainModule {

 @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [AccountModule::class])
    @ViewScope
    abstract fun bindInstanceIdService(): MyInstanceIdService


      @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideApplicationContext(application: Application): Context = application
 @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideStorageData(storage: MainStorage): StorageContract = storage

}
```

Here is ModuleTwo that is specific to a domain packages

```
@Module
abstract class AccountModule {
     @Module
    companion object {
        @ViewScope
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun providesAccountDelegator(accountDelegate: AccountDelegator): AccountDelegatorContract = accountDelegate

        @ViewScope
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun providesAccountControllerContract(accountNetworkController: AccountNetworkController): AccountControllerContract = accountNetworkController

    }

}
```

My app is organised in different packages that represent a part/domain of the app such as accounts, users, vehicle, message etc etc and with each domain has its own module which defines specific dependencies related to that domain.

My issue is that how can I use dependencies above located on different modules?

Edit: my appCOmponent looks like this

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MainModule::class,
AccountModule ::class))

interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {
    fun inject(MyApplication: MyApplication)
    fun inject(myInsanceIdService: MyInstanceIdService)
    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(applicaton: Application): Builder

        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

Comment: tried adding ContributesAndroidInjector and AndroidInjection.inject(this) and still no joy

Answer (score 0):

You add you `AccountModule` (with provision methods of `ViewScope` sope) to your AppComponent as well as your subcomponent (declared with @ContributesAndroidInjector bindInstanceIdService), so I wonder how/why this compiles at all. So first of all you should remove the AccountModule from your app component, since it has a different scope anyways and won't do you any good there.

Secondly, you call `DaggerApplicationComponent.inject(this)` in your `MyInstanceIdService`, although `ApplicationComponent` does not include a `inject(service : MyInstanceIdService)` method. Again, I don't see how/why this would compile. As already mentioned above, you registered a subcomponent (@ContributesAndroidInjector bindInstanceIdService) to inject your service, so you should *use it*. Your app component does not even have the correct scope to provide all of the objects.

Even worse, you create *another* `AppComponent` in your `MyInstanceIdService`, so even if this would work, you now have 2 singleton components providing 2 different instances of your "singleton" objects. Don't recreate components out of their scope. Use `MyApplication.getAppComponent()` and use that one!

So after removing the AccountModule from the AppComponent you should make your Application implement the `HasServiceInjector`, injecting/returning the dispatching injector like you do for your activities. Then inject your service by using `AndroidInjection.inject(this)`.

To sum up:

- Check your scopes. A `@Singleton` component can't provide `@ViewScope` things.
- Don't register modules with different scopes on components, they can't use it anyways
- Don't inject an object with a component of a different scope than you need
- Don't recreate components when creating subcomponents. Use the existing one!
- If you use `dagger.android` then don't create the components yourself, but implement the correct interface and use `AndroidInjection.inject()`

Comment: From my understanding and various sources and tutorials i have seen, You need to include the Module in the appComponent. If you take it out, how are the modules initialised and used then? Every article points that it is initialised in the AppComponent.

Also my code above compiles fine, well except for the error saying that my delegator cant be provided without a provides. Whilst the storage is provided perfectly.

I now tried to change scopes for them to all be @ViewScope and still had the same issue.

Comment: and also removed the DaggerAppComponent builder and just included the AndroidInjection.inject(this) and no joy still same error specifically about my delegator located on moduleTwo

Comment: Also, my code above has the inject(service: InstanceIdSerice) already